# bash - moving files based on information extracted from filename

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, move

Trying to create a script that will take a tv show video file and move it into the correct folder in my TV directory hierarchy.

ie.  example filenames:

```
archer.2009.s01e01.publichd.mkv
archer.s05e10.dimension.mkv
```

I would like these moved to: Television/Archer/Season 1/  and  Television/Archer/Season 5/    respectively and create them if they don't already exist.

Here's what I have so far, right now it's only sorting based on season for one particular show, Archer.  Planning to expand that once I get it working:

```
#!/bin/bash

for season in 01 02 03 04 05 #06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
do

    echo 'Season ' $season
    #find -iname *archer*s$season\*.*
    var=$(find -iname *archer*s$season\*.*)
    var=$(echo $var | cut -c 3-)
    echo $var

    var2=$(sed "s/0//" <<< $season)
    var3=$(echo "Season $var2/")
    echo $var3

    if [[ -z "$var" ]]
    then
        : 
    else
        mkdir -p /home/adam/Downloads/Television/Archer/$var3;
        mv "./$var" "/home/adam/Downloads/Television/Archer/$var3"
    fi

done
```

I'm having problems creating/moving the files to the $var3 directory variable.  It does have a space in the name which I know is giving me the problems.  I already have a large library of shows in this format though so I'm rather not change it.

Any help would be appreciated - I know the script is VERY primitive, I'm just piecing it together as I go.

Comment: _Planning to expand that once I get it working_. You'd better start learning good practices about shell scripting. Your style is terrible, inefficient and mostly wrong. Using more quotes will help a lot. You're using lots of useless subshells (4: all are useless); your `find` command is wrong (and useless since Bash globbing will do the job as well); learn about Bash parameter expansions; your use of `var3=$(echo "Season $var2/")` is awful. Pretty much every line is awful, actually. Please do something about all this before you expand your script `;)`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful criticism and providing suggestions to the things you thought could be better.  Oh wait... you didn't do that at all.... ;)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't fit in a comment `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around var3 when using it.

```
mkdir "$var3"
```

Comment: @user3621333 You can start by accept the answer first.